# Making my function return an error message

Tags: list, if-statement, f#

I'm trying to make my function return "invalid Input" when it finds an empty sublist.

```
let func (lst: 'a list list) =
    if List.contains [] lst then
        printfn "%s" "Invalid Input"
    else
        List.map List.head lst
```

This is what I've tried but this of course doesn't work since my if/else returns two different types.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Result` type:

```
let func lst =
    if List.contains [] lst
    then Error "Invalid input"
    else Ok (List.map List.head lst)
```

Comment: Nice answer! [Result on msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/results)  (with some infos on Railway oriented programming)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should raise an exception. By the way, you may want to use [`List.isEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.isempty%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D):

```
let func (lst: 'a list list) =
    if List.contains [] lst then
        raise (System.ArgumentException("Invalid Input"))
    else
        List.map List.head lst
```

You can also replace `raise` with `invalidArg "lst"`

```
let func (lst: 'a list list) = 
   if List.isEmpty lst then invalidArg "lst" "Input is empty"
   else List.map List.head lst
```

Learn more: [Exceptions | F# for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/exceptions/) or [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/exception-handling/index).

Then you can catch the exception to retrieve the exception.

Comment: Can I somehow avoid getting all of the error message included, and just the "Invalid Input" or "Input is empty"?

Comment: @wardz maybe dumetrulo's answer is more appropriate in your case. If you want the message of an exception use the `Message` property. [read this for more information](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/exceptions/#catching-exceptions)